# MySql Define foreign key with multiple columns throws error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

I have 2 tables. And queries are below.

```
CREATE TABLE `queue_service_settings` (
  `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `setting_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `setting_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `setting_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (app_id,app_id_type),
  KEY `index_qss_app_id` (`app_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_qss_setting_type` (`setting_type`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_qss_setting_key` (`setting_key`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_qss_channel_id` (`channel_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `queue_applications` (
  `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `callback_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`app_id_type`,`channel_id`),
  KEY `fk_qa_channel_id` (`channel_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_qa_app_id_app_id_type_channel_id` FOREIGN KEY (app_id,app_id_type,channel_id) REFERENCES queue_service_settings(app_id,app_id_type,channel_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And i am getting this error

> Cannot add foreign key constraint Create table
> 'event_processor_test/queue_applications' with foreign key constraint
> failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced
> columns appear as the first columns.

When i tried to define this 3 columns (app_id,app_id_type,channel_id) as primary key its ok but primary key should be just (app_id,app_id_type)

Comment: Should follow an SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in the foreign key must match the columns of the primary key referenced in the other table. You have two columns in the primary key of `queue_service_settings`, so you should have two columns in the foreign key that references it.

```
CREATE TABLE `queue_applications` (
  `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `callback_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`,`app_id_type`,`channel_id`),
  KEY `fk_qa_channel_id` (`channel_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_qa_app_id_app_id_type_channel_id` 
    FOREIGN KEY (app_id,app_id_type) 
    REFERENCES queue_service_settings(app_id,app_id_type)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: But when i try with just channel_id i can add foreign key to table.

Comment: InnoDB allows some non-standard combinations, but this is not recommended. The foreign key should reference only the primary key or unique key in the other table. The columns should be the same, in data type, number of columns, and order in the constraint.